Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce... , building Flutter iOS app
I was trying to build the ipa for my Flutter app, but this error came out:
[   +3 ms] Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce

'/Users/antonio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-edmltyztwaxqqcevfshktmkpdgia/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/FirebaseFirestore_Privac
        y.bundle'
        
[   +6 ms] "flutter ipa" took 29.359ms.
[  +10 ms] Encountered error while archiving for device.
[        ] 
        #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
        #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:680:7)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #2      BuildIOSArchiveCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:425:50)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1389:27)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:355:9)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:295:5)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:119:9)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
        <asynchronous suspension>
        #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
        <asynchronous suspension>

Now, I'm using Firebase Firestore, Firebase Storage and Firebase Authentication in my app, and using the precompiled SDK provided here, version ^10.24.0. I put this into my Podfile
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.24.0'

It works when I build the app on the local simulator, but it gives the problem when I try to build the app via flutter build ipa.
Please give me some ideas on how to fix this error.
Thank you.

SOLVED
It was a problem with caches of the pods, solved thanks to the response to this issue.
Simply, run this commands on your terminal, one by one:
flutter clean
cd ios && rm -rf Pods && rm Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all

